# Redux with multiple react root nodes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, redux

Is it possible to have a single redux store serve multiple react apps ... Or root components on the same page?

Will the same `<Provider />` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not.

The store can be reused without problem, since it is nothing more than a container that accepts actions and keeps/updates the state. It is not bound to a specific react app or any app for that matter. Your apps should have a dependency on the store, not the other way around.

The react-redux `Provider` element does nothing more than injecting the store into its child components and while it is a convenient and clean solution to enable access to the store, it is not necessary for your app development at all.

I would just give it a shot, try to implement and see if you hit any specific road blocks.

Comment: Thank you, I will report back.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said, you certainly can.

I'm a bit biased but do check out [React Habitat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-habitat).

It's a framework that will help you do just that.